# Why don't strings "exist" and memory of chars vs memory of strings?

Tags: c, string

I've studied C programming at university for 4 months. My professor always said that strings don't really exist. Since I finished those 2 small courses, I really started programming (java). I can't remember WHY strings don't really exist. I wasn't concerned about this before, but I'm curious now. Why don't they exist? And do they exist in Java? I know it has to do something with that "under the hood strings are just characters", but does that mean that strings are all saved as multiple characters etc? And doesn't that take more memory?

Comment: In C strings are represented as a sequence of characters followed by a special character marking that its the end of the string. You, the programmer, have to allocate memory for these characters. The reason your professor might assert that "strings don't really exist" is because they are really just characters in a certain order. There is no "string" keyword in C that you can just declare.

Comment: ah that's refreshing, thanks! and indeed, it's ended with /0 i believe.

Comment: is this different from java? @chevybow

Comment: Very different. There is a native, *immutable* String type in Java. You can also declare an array of *char*, if you are feeling like it, but one would not normally null-terminate them.

Comment: Strings in Java are objects.

Comment: so in java strings arent a sequence of characters but are saved as literal strings? @RobertColumbia

Comment: Yes, they are literally saved as literal strings. Keep in mind, though, that Java, like any high or mid-level language, abstracts some things. At the very bottom there are only ones and zeroes.

Comment: @RobertColumbia to go off of that- I think its very misleading to say that strings don't exist in a language like C (just because there is no way to explicitly define a string using the string keyword). Strings are more of a concept that we as programmers use to think about certain types of data. Strings definitely exist in C, but as a low level programming language- you have to better understand their implementation opposed to a high level language like java where you can just do `String x = new String('blep')`

Comment: @chevybow that's exactly what I was trying to say in my last comment about abstraction. Java Strings are just an abstraction, though a more robust and more intuitive one than C "strings". In the end it's all ones and zeroes.

Comment: this conversation remembers me of what i've forgotten about the courses haha anyway thanks buddies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `string` *type* does not exist in C, but *C strings* do exist. They are defined as a null terminated character array.  For example:

```
char buffer1[] = "this is a C string";//string literal
```

creates a C string that looks like this in memory:

```
|t|h|i|s| |i|s| |a| |C| |s|t\r|i|n|g|\0|?|?|?|  
<                 string               >
```

Note that this is not a string:

```
char *buffer2;
```

Until it contains a series of `char` terminated by a `\0`, it is just a pointer to `char`. (`char *`)

```
buffer2 = calloc(strlen(buffer1)+1, 1);
strcpy(buffer2, buffer1); //now buffer2 is pointing to a string
```

References:
*[Strings in C 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/)*
*[Strings in C 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*
*[Stirngs in C 3](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring05/V22.0201-001/c_tutorial/classes/String.html)*
*[and many more...](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=Z4MFW6fBGoGowATX8YiIDw&q=strings+in+C&oq=strings+in+C&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.1348.3096.0.3401.13.9.0.0.0.0.383.949.2-1j2.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.3.948.0..35i39k1j0i131k1.0.ezzp1GMaZi4)*

***Edit:***
(to address discussion in comments on strings:)

Based on the following definition:  (From *[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*)

> Strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by
>   a null character '\0'.

First, since *null termination* is integral to a conversation about C strings, here are some clarifications:

- The term `NULL` is a *pointer*, typically defined as `(void*)0)`, or
  just `0`. It can be, and typically is used to initialize pointer
  variables.
- The term '\0' is a *character*.  In C, it means exactly the same
  thing as the integer constant `0`.  (same value `0`, same type
  `int`).  It is used to   initialize `char` arrays.

Things that *are* strings:

```
char string[] = {'\0'}; //zero length or _empty_ string with `sizeof` 1.
```

In memory:

```
|\0|
```

...

```
char string[10] = {'\0'} also zero length or _empty_ with `sizeof` 10.
```

In memory:

```
|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|
```

...

```
char string[] = {"string"}; string of length 6, and `sizeof` 7.
```

In memory:

```
|s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
```

...

```
char [2][5] = {{0}}; 2 strings, each with zero length, and `sizeof` 5.
```

In memory:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0| (note 0 equivalent to \0)
```

...

```
char *buf = {"string"};//string literal.
```

In memory:

```
|s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
```

Things that *are not* strings:

```
char buf[6] = {"string"};//space for 6, but "string" requires 7 for null termination.
```

In Memory:

```
|s|t|r|i|n|g|  //no null terminator
          |end of space in memory.
```

...

```
char *buf = {0};//pointer to char (`char *`).
```

In memory:

```
|0| //null initiated pointer residing at address of `buf`  (eg. 0x00123650)
```

Comment: thanks for the references, this reminds me everything again. I was like "I swear i used variable String multiple times with C", but i think i called the char sequences "str", and then str.length etc.. That's why my mind was mixed up i think lol

Comment: C has a str* functions, however they depend on being pointed at a valid sequence of chars terminated with a \0, or by defining how long the "string" is in the function call. They're easy to do wrong, which leads to crashes and buffer overruns and security vulnerabilities. This is one reason for the popularity of managed languages like .net and others.

Comment: @TerryCarmen - You are making a point, I just do not know what it is.  And careful... Part of your definition of a string: "_as a sequence of chars terminated with a \0, or a number of chars with a known upper bound."_ is correct, but part is not.  A string in C is pure and simple: an array of `char` terminated with a `NULL`.  (you got that part right) but _"or a number of chars with a known upper bound."_ is not correct.  If I use the `strlen` function on a string, it will tell me the length, but that value length does not include the `NULL` terminator.

Comment: There are no strings. There are only sequences bytes interpreted as chars. They can be null terminated, but are not required to be. This is why the strn* functions exist; for cases where the null terminator is missing or is ignored.

Comment: @TerryCarmen - Kindly read the _"Strings in C"_ information I linked above, it clearly describes C strings as requiring a null termination.  Without a null termination, you are correct, it is just an array of `char`.  By the way, it is _[undefined behavior](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs)_ to pass a non-null terminated `char` array to a string function, such as `stcpy()`, or `strcmp()`.

Comment: But still there is the variable "string" in C

Comment: @wutBruh - Well, I'm not certain if that is a question, or a statement.  Either way, yes there can be a string literal that contains the content 'string', and it can even be stored in a _variable_ declared as `char string[7]="string".  But, there is no `string` type, per se.   (Also, see edit portion at the bottom of my post above.)

Comment: "defined as a `NULL` terminated" confuses the use of `NULL`, a _null pointer constant_ with `'\0'`, the _null character_.  Better to avoid `NULL` when discussing the end of a _string_:  Maybe: "defined as a _null character_ terminated"

Comment: Detail about "The term `NULL` is a pointer, typically defined as `(void*)0)`, or just `0`.":  When `NULL` is defined as `0`, it is an `int`, not a pointer.  A weakness in C, IMO.

Comment: @chux - I edited to add your suggestion, and agree, duality of NULL in C is at the very least confusing.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Once again, I thank you all for the conversations and elaborations on the question :) Y'all cleared my mind and gave some extra information as well

Answer (score 1):

Strings don't exist in C as a data type. There is int, char, byte, etc., but no "string".

This means you can declare a variable as an int, but not as a "string" because there is no data type named "string" .

The closest C has to a string is an array of chars, or a char * to a section of memory. The actual string is up to the programmer to define, as a sequence of chars terminated with a \0, or a number of chars with a known upper bound.

Comment: but yet there is the variable string in C

Comment: _String_ exist in the standard C library.  It is specified as a term defined as "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Comment: The library is not the language, it's just a library. I'm not saying that strings are impossible, I'm answering the OP's question as to why his professor said that "strings don't exist in C"

Comment: gotcha.. That's totally true, it's just the library

Comment: True the C standard library is a library, yet not just any library.  It is defined in the same specification as the C language proper and forms the basis for _portable_ code.  Although rare C code does not use any of the standard C library, learning about C is not done without it any more than not using `NULL`, `abs()`, `printf()`, `INTMAX`, `malloc()`, and functions that depend on _string_.